# Avoid a short carry-over title of "list of figures" at the top of the next page

Tags: pdftex

There is a carry-over title of "list of figures"  at the top of the pages company profile and problem statement and objective.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=32mm,rmargin=32mm}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
    \onehalfspacing
    \usepackage{txfonts}
    %\usefont{T1}{tnr}{m}{sl}
    \makeatletter
    \makeatother
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
    \usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
    %\renewcommand{\section}{\MakeUppercase}
    %\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
    %\usepackage[options]{natbib}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Title Page
    \input{titlepage}
    \cleardoublepage
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \input{certpdf}
    \input{ack}
    \input{abs}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \input{CompanyProfile}
    \input{ProblemStatement}
    \input{LiteratureReview}
    \input{ch1}
    \input{Results}
    \input{Conclusion}
    \input{References}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{document}
```

Please help me how to remove it.

```
\title{}
\author{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace{0.1in}
{\LARGE \bf Employee Attendance Portal} \\
\end{center}
\begin{center}
%\vspace{0.2in}
%{\large Dissertation} \\
\vspace{0.6in}
{\large \it A project report submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for Colloquium } \\
\vspace{0.6in}
\vspace{0.5in}
{\large \it by\\}
\vspace{0.3in}
{\large \bf Sumit Raj (2013IPG-112)}\\
%{\normalsize (2008IPG-48)}\\
%{\normalsize }\\
\end {center}
\vspace{0.8in}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=1.2in]{iiitm}}
\end{figure}
%\vspace{0.1in}
\begin{center}
{\Large \bf ABV INDIAN INSTITUTE OF INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY AND MANAGEMENT\\
GWALIOR- 474 015\\}
\vspace{0.2in}
{\Large \bf 2017\\}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
%\pagestyle{headings}
```

Here is the code.of titlepage.tex.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CERTIFICATE}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{9.jpeg}}
\end{figure} 
\end{center}
```

Here is the code of certpdf.tex

Comment: I think you should include a MWE (minimal working example) that shows your problem. I tried compiling it, but the file `titlepage.tex` is missing.

Comment: @logo_writer actually i have included all pages in Thesis_main.tex and don't know how to do create MWE  and also there is a blank page after the title page.

Comment: For the time being, just make a document, the smallest one possible, that reproduces your problem and has no `\input` (it would be only a `.tex` file). Such file help us identify the root cause of your problem easier. A quick review of your code reveals a lot of `\input`s, which requires a handful of files just to compile.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) for an exhaustive walk through of creating a MWE!

Comment: @Skillmon yeah...it worked...thanks...i need one more help there is blank page after the title page i want to remove that page...can you tell me how?

Comment: The blank page might result from the contents in your titlepage-file, so without knowing its contents, I might be unable to help.

Comment: You should not put the `\begin{document}` statement into that file. It unnecessarily obfuscates your code.

Comment: @Skillmon when i remove it, it throws an error "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}."

Comment: That's why you should put it into your main file above your titlepage. And don't put a `figure` environment on your titlepage. You don't want that thingy to float away. Just use the `\includegraphics` without it.

Comment: Oh, and no need to `\setcounter{page}{1}`, the `\pagenumbering{roman}` does it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer so it is better formatted. Also I removed everything not related to the question (that's how a MWE could look like).

`\markboth{left}{right}` sets the headmarks. The "carrying over" title was one of those marks, so invoking `\markboth{}{}` does clear that.

The `titlepage` environment breaks the page after it. So there is no need to use `\clearpage` after it. That's most likely the cause of your empty page.

The problem of the empty page is caused by the very large image you want to insert. Does it have to be that large? You should leave out the `figure` environment around it, and change its dimensions to make it fit on that page. Or you could tell LaTeX how big the box is (though the image is bigger).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\title{foo}\author{bar}

\begin{document}
% Title Page
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering%
    ~\vfill%
    {\huge My Title}\\
    \vspace{2cm}%
    {\large Author}%
    \vfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage% or \cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}% correct number in ToC
\listoffigures
\clearpage% or \cleardoublepage
\markboth{}{}% empty the headmarks

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{bar}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{baz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't remove the blank page after the title page and due to that blank page my numbering are also wrong...how to remove that blank page...?

Comment: @Simranjeet As noted above, I can't tell without seeing your title page code.

Comment: i have added the code of my title page...

Comment: still it is not removed...

Comment: @Simranjeet what are the contents of `certpdf`?

Comment: added that code too...